# Terraform setproduct function with more than two lists

Tags: terraform

How to use terraform setproduct function with more than 2 lists in the below scenario or is there any other way to achieve the end result.

In main.tf file I have the following data.

```
$ cat main.tf
variable "nodes" {
  default = ["1", "2", "3"]
}

variable "ebs_volumes" {
  default = [
    {
      ebs_name = "/dev/xdba"
      ebs_size = "50"
      ebs_type = "gp2"
    },
    {
      ebs_name = "/dev/xdbb"
      ebs_size = "20"
      ebs_type = "gp2"
    }
  ]
}

locals {
  ebs_name = [for i in var.ebs_volumes : i.ebs_name]
  ebs_size = [for i in var.ebs_volumes : i.ebs_size]
  ebs_type = [for i in var.ebs_volumes : i.ebs_type]
}

locals {
  node_disks = { for pair in setproduct(var.nodes, local.ebs_name) : "${pair[0]}:${pair[1]}" => {
    node_index = pair[0]
    ebs_name   = pair[1]
    ebs_size   = [for i in var.ebs_volumes : i.ebs_size]
    ebs_type   = [for i in var.ebs_volumes : i.ebs_type]
  } }
}

output "combined" {
  value = local.node_disks
}
```

When I run terraform apply I get the following result

```
    $ terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

combined = {
  "1:/dev/xdba" = {
    "ebs_name" = "/dev/xdba"
    "ebs_size" = [
      "50",
      "20",
    ]
    "ebs_type" = [
      "gp2",
      "gp2",
    ]
    "node_index" = "1"
  }
  "1:/dev/xdbb" = {
    "ebs_name" = "/dev/xdbb"
    "ebs_size" = [
      "50",
      "20",
    ]
    "ebs_type" = [
      "gp2",
      "gp2",
    ]
    "node_index" = "1"
  }
  "2:/dev/xdba" = {
    "ebs_name" = "/dev/xdba"
    "ebs_size" = [
      "50",
      "20",
    ]
    "ebs_type" = [
      "gp2",
      "gp2",
    ]
    "node_index" = "2"
  }
  "2:/dev/xdbb" = {
    "ebs_name" = "/dev/xdbb"
    "ebs_size" = [
      "50",
      "20",
    ]
    "ebs_type" = [
      "gp2",
      "gp2",
    ]
    "node_index" = "2"
  }
  "3:/dev/xdba" = {
    "ebs_name" = "/dev/xdba"
    "ebs_size" = [
      "50",
      "20",
    ]
    "ebs_type" = [
      "gp2",
      "gp2",
    ]
    "node_index" = "3"
  }
  "3:/dev/xdbb" = {
    "ebs_name" = "/dev/xdbb"
    "ebs_size" = [
      "50",
      "20",
    ]
    "ebs_type" = [
      "gp2",
      "gp2",
    ]
    "node_index" = "3"
  }
}
```

Instead I want to be able to have the result as shown below (psudo code):

```
combined = {
  "1:/dev/xvdb" = {
    "disk_dev_path" = "/dev/xvda"
    "node_name" = "1"
    "disk_size" = "10"
    "disk_type" = "gp2"
  }
  "1:/dev/xvdc" = {
    "disk_dev_path" = "/dev/xvdb"
    "node_name" = "1"
    "disk_size" = "30"
    "disk_type" = "gp2"
  }
  "2:/dev/xvdb" = {
    "disk_dev_path" = "/dev/xvda"
    "node_name" = "2"
    "disk_size" = "10"
    "disk_type" = "gp2"
  }
  "2:/dev/xvdc" = {
    "disk_dev_path" = "/dev/xvdb"
    "node_name" = "2"
    "disk_size" = "30"
    "disk_type" = "gp2"
  }
  "3:/dev/xvdb" = {
    "disk_dev_path" = "/dev/xvda"
    "node_name" = "3"
    "disk_size" = "10"
    "disk_type" = "gp2"
  }
  "3:/dev/xvdc" = {
    "disk_dev_path" = "/dev/xvdb"
    "node_name" = "3"
    "disk_size" = "30"
    "disk_type" = "gp2"
  }
}
```

How to achieve this?

I need this in order to use this in **for_each** to create ec2 instances and ebs volumes and attach them respectively whenever user adds an input in the variable using our ec2 module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, maybe you could use use a **double for-loop** with `flatten` for that. Seems more natural for me.

Below is a **working example**:

```
variable "nodes" {
  default = ["1", "2", "3"]
}

variable "ebs_volumes" {
  default = [
    {
      ebs_name = "/dev/xdba"
      ebs_size = "50"
      ebs_type = "gp2"
    },
    {
      ebs_name = "/dev/xdbb"
      ebs_size = "20"
      ebs_type = "gp2"
    }
  ]
}

locals {

    node_disks2 = {for idx, value in flatten([for node in var.nodes: 
                   [for volume in var.ebs_volumes:
                    { 
                        node_index = node
                        ebs_name   = volume.ebs_name
                        ebs_size   = volume.ebs_size
                        ebs_type   = volume.ebs_type
                   }]
               ]): idx => value}
}

output "combined" {
  value = local.node_disks2
}
```

Output:

```
ombined = {
  "0" = {
    "ebs_name" = "/dev/xdba"
    "ebs_size" = "50"
    "ebs_type" = "gp2"
    "node_index" = "1"
  }
  "1" = {
    "ebs_name" = "/dev/xdbb"
    "ebs_size" = "20"
    "ebs_type" = "gp2"
    "node_index" = "1"
  }
  "2" = {
    "ebs_name" = "/dev/xdba"
    "ebs_size" = "50"
    "ebs_type" = "gp2"
    "node_index" = "2"
  }
  "3" = {
    "ebs_name" = "/dev/xdbb"
    "ebs_size" = "20"
    "ebs_type" = "gp2"
    "node_index" = "2"
  }
  "4" = {
    "ebs_name" = "/dev/xdba"
    "ebs_size" = "50"
    "ebs_type" = "gp2"
    "node_index" = "3"
  }
  "5" = {
    "ebs_name" = "/dev/xdbb"
    "ebs_size" = "20"
    "ebs_type" = "gp2"
    "node_index" = "3"
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks great, but my only concern with this approach is that key has a running number from 0... , this would pose a problem if the order of var.ebs_volumes changes, then the key would change, hence forcing the resources to be recreated. If you swap the order by changing /dev/xdba to /dev/xdbb and /dev/xdbb to /dev/xdba for var.ebs_volumes, you can see that the keys changing. Do you think the same way?

Comment: I made a small change to your code and now it works as expected, here is what I did

``locals {

    node_disks2 = {for idx in flatten([for node in var.nodes:
                   [for volume in var.ebs_volumes:
                    {
                        node_index = node
                        ebs_name   = volume.ebs_name
                        ebs_size   = volume.ebs_size
                        ebs_type   = volume.ebs_type
                   }]
               ]): "${idx.node_index}:${idx.ebs_name}" => idx}
}``

Comment: @youhoome No problem. Thanks for letting me know.